# Auto create new directory for new user on Windows File Server

Tags: active-directory, user-management, file-server

On our network we give each user a network share at **\\fileserver\users\username**.  These are intentionally NOT set up as their *home directory*, and are instead mapped by a login script every time the user logs on.  For new users, this drive mapping fails, since the folder does not exist yet.

Is there a way that when we create a new user in Active Directory, it can automatically create the folder at \\fileserver\users\username?  Or alternatively, that the folder can be created the first time it is accessed?

Failing that, can somebody show me how to manually create a folder with vbscript?

*edit*

So it appears that the **logon script** solution is not going to work for me, because the user doesn't have permission to create folders in \\fileserver\users. (and the script runs with the user's privileges)  **Any other ideas?**

Comment: Brent, how do you map to the user folder when login? I am aware I can create a script to map to a directory but how to a specific directory for each user?

Comment: strUserName = gobjWshNetwork.UserName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the permissions of \\fileserver\users as described in the Microsoft TechNet article entitled "Security Considerations when Configuring Folder Redirection" http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775853(WS.10).aspx.  The situation you are describing is exactly the situation in which folder redirection operates.  The permissions described will allow regular user accounts to create their own folders and then to access them, but they will not allow users to access folders belonging to others.  Thus, a logon script will operate as you desire once these permissions are set.

For what it's worth, your next step along the road to best practices is to actually *use* folder redirection and get rid of drive mapping altogether.  Windows surfaces redirected folders throughout the user interface, and so it is easier for users to find a redirected folder than a mapped drive.  Also, folder redirection requires no scripting, and folder creation is automatic, which is what you want.

Comment: +1 Many of MS's Group Policy changes are providing features that encourage you to discontinue login scripts, and years of experience indicate that is a Good Thing!

Answer (score 1):

```
On Error Resume Next
set objFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystem")
If Not objFSO.FolderExists("\\fileserver\users\username") Then
    result = objFSO.CreateFolder("\\fileserver\users\username"
    If result = 0 AND Err.number = 0 Then Wscript.Echo Chr(34) & "\\fileserver\users\username" & Chr(34) " -created"
End If
```

Comment: To do it upon first login set a login script on the user account in AD and call the above from the login script.

Comment: A user will not have permissions to create a directory at that level.  How can I work around that?

Comment: This script is is intended for an Admin to run after creating the account.  If you'd like I can easily edit the code so that it would prompt the admin for the path/username, and then as part of your regular procedures you could just run this after creating the user account, or better yet you could incorporate the code to create the user account and then create the folder.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for.  I want to address the (common) problem that the admin forgets to create the \\fileserver\user\username directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do things in a bit of a different fashion and use a script to create everything, including the user account.  This way you could also include the home share as part of the new user script.  There are a ton of examples out there on how to modify AD via script.

Comment: I'm still hoping for a more automatic solution.  When we had our fileserver on Linux, it would auto-create a missing directory the first time a user logged in.  That was nice.

Comment: Granted, but you can't get much more automated than a catch-all script (outside of having to develop said script...)